# Contar cantidad de un carácter especifico de una cadena en C

Tags: c, string

Quiero contar la veces que se repite una letra en una cadena dada.

Por ejemplo: la cadena que ingreso es "alan".

Después pido que el usuario me diga que letra quiere contar, en este ejemplo la a.

> El resultado evidentemente es 2 para la cadena "alan"

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *alfabeto;
    int n, j, num, contador, i;   
    char letra, w1[50];
    alfabeto = (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    printf("Ingrese el tamaño del alfabeto:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Ingrese el alfabeto:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%s",&alfabeto[i]);
    }
    printf("\nIngrese la cadena:\n");
    scanf("%s", &w1);
    printf("introduce letra a buscar\n");
    scanf("%s", &letra);
    contador = 0;
    num = strlen(w1);
    for  (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < num - 1; j++) {
            if (w1[j] == alfabeto[i])
            {
                contador += 1;
                letra = alfabeto[i];
            }
        }
    }
    if (contador != 0)
        printf("el numero de letras %c es %d\n", letra, contador);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Para qué es el alfabeto? `&alfabeto[i]` es un `char`, pero estás leyendo un string `%s`. No estás controlando que `n<=100`. ¿Por qué no hacer `malloc` de `n` directamente? `w1` ya es la dirección de memoria del array, equivale a `&w1[0]`. `&w1` es la dirección donde está el puntero, algo que no te sirve en este caso. Más adelante de nuevo usas `%s` para `letra`, en lugar de `%c`. Recuerda que puedes hacer `contador++` directamente. Por último, te falta indicar cuál es el exacto problema que tuviste. Recomiendo que corrijas el código y actualices la publicación indicando cuál es la falla.

Answer (score 3):

Para iterar por las letras del abecedario no hace falta un array. Si echas un vistazo a cualquier tabla ascii, verás que a cada símbolo le corresponde un número. El sistema utiliza realmente esos números, los símbolos los reserva para el momento de representar algo en pantalla. Es decir, los caracteres ascii son, para el sistema, números.

Siguiendo con las características de la tabla ASCII, fíjate que los símbolos que representan las letras del alfabeto están en orden secuencial.

Es decir, para recorrer todas las letras nos basta con:

```
for( char letra='a'; letra <= 'z'; letra++ )
{
}
```

Aun así, si insistes en introducir el alfabeto a mano, puedes hacerlo de dos formas:

1. Leyendo todas las letras del tirón. En este caso usas `%s`:

   ```
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char *alfabeto = (char*)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s",alfabeto);
   ```
2. Leer caracter a caracter. En este caso debes usar `%c`:

   ```
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char *alfabeto = (char*)malloc(n*sizeof(char));
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%c",&alfabeto[i]);
    }
   ```

Nota que, en el primer caso, reservamos espacio para `n+1` caracteres. Al usar `%s` hay que contar con el terminador de cadena que `scanf` añadirá al final de la secuencia.

Por cierto, en el segundo caso asumimos que todos los caracteres se introducen seguidos, sin saltos de línea de por medio...

Si comparas esto con tu código, te darás cuenta que has mezclado ambas lecturas, resultando un engendro que puede pisar memoria y dejar el sistema en un estado inconsistente.

Seguimos con tu código ... después de procesar el alfabeto pretendes leer la cadena:

```
scanf("%s",&w1);
```

Pues bien, fíjate que `w1` es un array de caracteres. Una característica de C es que los arrays decaen en punteros, por lo que **sobra el `&`**:

```
scanf("%s", w1);
```

Y finalmente lees la letra a buscar:

```
scanf("%s",&letra);
```

Nuevamente, usas `%s` en vez de `%c`, por lo que lees una cadena de caracteres en vez de un caracter suelto (y ya hemos visto que esto tiene implicaciones). Lo corregimos:

```
scanf("%c",&letra);
```